# vmrun error - Home directory is not accessible: permission denied

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, vmware, root

After updating my linux server from Red Hat 4.8.3-9 to Ubuntu 5.2.1-22.
I've reinstalled VMWare on this new machine to host two virtual machines like I did on Red Hat.
I have a script to stop the running virtual machines, copy them to a backup machine and restart them again.

This works on the Ubuntu setup but each time a VMWare command is executed as root(ex. sudo vmrun list), I get the message:
    `Home directory is not accessible: permission denied.`
The command is still executed but the error must indicate there is something wrong, how can I fix this?

This issue does not occur when the command is issued without sudo.

Comment: Does it also occur with `sudo -E`?

Comment: When I run sudo -E vmrun list, the previous error is gone. But then I receive this message:"XDG_RUNTIME_DIR (/run/user/1000) is not owned by us (uid 0), but by uid 1000! (This could e g happen if you try to connect to a non-root PulseAudio as a root user, over the native protocol. Don't do that."